# How to Update Cart in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to make a Shopping Cart in Xamarin. I am having a problem like this.

I have an addtocart button on the product detail page

```
        var getprd = ((ViewProductViewModel)BindingContext).ProductInfo;
        var data = new List<CartUser>();

        int idprod = getprd.IDProduct;
        string nameprod = getprd.Name;
        Int64 priceprod = getprd.Price;
        Int64 priceoldprod = getprd.PriceOld;
        string imgprod = getprd.Images;
        int numadd = 1;


        var productInfoget = new CartUser()
        {
            IDProduct = idprod,
            NameProduct = nameprod,
            PriceProduct = priceprod,
            PriceProductOld = priceoldprod,
            ImagesProduct = imgprod,
            NumberProduct = numadd
        };
        data.Add(productInfoget);
        Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
```

When I click the button, I want the product to be added to the cart. Here I set: `Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));` is the Customer shopping cart.

Everything seems fine.

However I want to check if this Product is already in cart then next time Click Addtocart button it will update quantity based on IDProduct condition. If the product is not in the cart. Then add that product to the cart.

```
        //Check the product already exists in the cart
        int idprodadd = productInfoget.IDProduct;
        var addcart = Preferences.Get("CartUser", "defaultcart");
        if(addcart != "defaultcart")
        {
            var getitem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(addcart);
            foreach (var p in getitem)
            {
                int idprodget = p.IDProduct;
                
                if(idprodget == idprodadd)
                {
                    p.NumberProduct = p.NumberProduct + 1;
                }    
                else
                {
                    data.Add(productInfoget);
                    Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
                }
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add(productInfoget);
            Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        }
```

I have a problem right here. When I debug, quantity doesn't update when it matches IDProduct and can't add product to cart when it doesn't match IDProduct.

Full command:

```
        var getprd = ((ViewProductViewModel)BindingContext).ProductInfo;
        var data = new List<CartUser>();

        int idprod = getprd.IDProduct;
        string nameprod = getprd.Name;
        Int64 priceprod = getprd.Price;
        Int64 priceoldprod = getprd.PriceOld;
        string imgprod = getprd.Images;
        int numadd = 1;


        var productInfoget = new CartUser()
        {
            IDProduct = idprod,
            NameProduct = nameprod,
            PriceProduct = priceprod,
            PriceProductOld = priceoldprod,
            ImagesProduct = imgprod,
            NumberProduct = numadd
        };

        int idprodadd = productInfoget.IDProduct;

        //Check the product already exists in the cart
        var addcart = Preferences.Get("CartUser", "defaultcart");
        if(addcart != "defaultcart")
        {
            var getitem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(addcart);
            foreach (var p in getitem)
            {
                int idprodget = p.IDProduct;
                
                if(idprodget == idprodadd)
                {
                    p.NumberProduct = p.NumberProduct + 1;
                }    
                else
                {
                    data.Add(productInfoget);
                    Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
                }
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add(productInfoget);
            Preferences.Set("CartUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        }
```

Ask for help from everyone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. According to your code, you can use **ObservableCollection** to
   store data. When the value of ObservableCollection is modified, the
   xaml page will also be modified accordingly.
2. Inside your for loop, as long as `idprodget == idprodadd` is not
   established, `data.Add(productInfoget)` will be triggered; Therefore,
   multiple duplicate data will be repeatedly added to the list.

   It is recommended that you write
   `data.Add(productInfoget);` outside the loop.